# Greek language package for version CE 1.9.0

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, language-package

I am looking for Greek language package for version CE 1.9.0.1. Does anyone have an idea where I can get the language packs I need?

Comment: I guess you already found this. It works with 1.9.0.1. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-greek-greece-language-pack.html

Comment: its for ce .16 and my version is ce 1.9

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/versedi/Magento-Locales

Comment: I am looking at  https://web.archive.org/web/20140717210430/http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/         -> Greek (Greece)

Hope it works for me

Comment: Going to try this: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-experience/internationalization-localization.html?id=12816&s=7&pl=0&eb=0&hp=0&q=greek&t=0&p=1 

linked to http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/greek-regions.html

Comment: You can add that as your own answer.

Comment: Will do after implementation and testing.

Comment: Cool! You cann accept your own answer in 48 hours to mark the question als resolved (if no one else has a better one ;-) ) http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @AnnaVölkl Ok and its really good answer. Thanks All for your time and attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Languages sources to download:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-experience/internationalization-localization.html?utm_source=mc&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=translations

if any language is not found on magentocommerce (above link) then use below one: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20140717210430/http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/

I found all desired packages :)